# Upgrade to 12.3 crashes Front end and Kernel after evaluating cell in any notebook

Tags: bugs, front-end, windows, crash, kernel-startup

Running Mathematica on Windows 10. Previous installed version was 12.1.

This occurs on any notebook including created new one. My
Mathematica worked just fine when it originally ran on 12.1. Not sure what to do. My first intuition is to uninstall then reinstall.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: In case it matters, which operating system are you using?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert my bad. Windows 10.

Comment: I don't know if a crash on Windows generates any logs.  It could be worth doing a checksum on the downloaded installation files to ensure that they weren't corrupted.

Comment: @mikado i dont know how to do that. ill reinstall. if that dont worki ill revert to 12.1/

Comment: @JulesManson - what did technical support say when you contacted them about this?

Comment: @JasonB I am using the student version. I dont know if its even eligible for live customer support. I ended up reinstalling 12.3. it appears a bit more stable however any large hit on kernel such as "Evaluate Notebook" crashes everything (front end and kernel)

Comment: I've heard that 12.3 uses DirectX API while older versions don't and may produce troubles under certain architectures. Try to contact the support.